# Have to perform an action when a batch job is completed

Tags: spring-batch

I have implemented Spring batch successfully but I am stuck at one point. I need to perform an action once my batch job is completed.

I can not perform the actions in a step because once the job fully completed only I can do this.

I will tell the scenario, 
*Step 1:* Pull data from reader, convert the data in processor and write to database.

*Step 2:* Read the data from database, apply the logic and convert in processor and write it to database.

The above is done and working fine. Once the above steps are completed, I have to compare the data which is received from api with data in db then I have to remove the records from my db which are not part of api data. I cant do this as a step since order of data from api is not same all the time.

I am new to Spring batch and tried to find a way but not able to arrive at conclusion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding your code helps others understand your needs in a better manner, please post your code here!

Comment: I will tell the scenario, Step 1: Pull data from reader, convert the data in processor and write to database. Step 2: Read the data from database, apply the logic and convert in processor and write it to database. The above is done and working fine. Once the above steps are completed, I have to compare the data which is received from api with data in db then I have to remove the records from my db which are not part of api data. I cant do this as a step since order of data from api is not same all the time.

Comment: Please add the above details to your question itself, as the others would lose track of these comments!

Comment: It is unclear why you can't run the comparison in a step. You can use a `JobExecutionListener` to run something at the start or the end of the job but I guess this would have the same problem.

Comment: BPavanKumar MartinHauner - Thank you, JobExecutionListener has worked for me, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // used spring boot + spring batch 2.x

//your config class {

  @Bean
    public Job myjob() {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("myjob")
             .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
             .flow(readData())
             .end()
             .listener(myjoblistener()).build();
        }

    @Bean
        public JobExecutionListener myjoblistener() {

            JobExecutionListener listener = new JobExecutionListener() {

                @Override
                public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

                    flatfiletoWrite = new HashSet<>();

                    try {
                        Files.write(Paths.get(""), Arrays.asList("foo"),
                                StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //sysout("Job has been completed");
                }
            };

            return listener ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Martin Hauner said, `JobExecutionListener` will provide a hook method called [afterJob()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionListener.html#afterJob-org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution-).

Please also note you should register the listener in your job.

```
<job id="exampleJob">
    <step id="step1" />
    <step id="step2" />
    <listeners>
        <listener ref="yourJobListener" />
    </listeners>
</job>

<bean id="yourJobListener" class="com.example.job.listener.YourJobListener" />
```